# How do you apply a list of lambda functions to a single element using an iterator?

Tags: python, list, lambda, iterator, yield

I want to apply a list of lambda functions to a single element using an iterable that has to be created with yield.

The list of lambda functions would have something like:

```
[<function <lambda> at 0x1d310c8>, <function <lambda> at 0x1d355f0>]
```

And I want to apply every function, from left to right , to a single element using yield to construct an iterable to iterate the list

Comment: *that has to be created with yield* - Why?

Comment: Heh...4 almost identical answers -  I think this is a good example that sometimes we do have "one obvious way of doing it" in Python

Comment: @jsbueno: Not too much of a surprise -- the use of `yield` was mandatory after all.  Otherwise, there certainly would have been `(f(x) for f in func_list)` as well.

Comment: @jsbueno: In most languages "use a loop" is the one obvious answer to the question "how do I do something for all elements in a list"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def apply_all(functions, item):
    for f in functions:
        yield f(item)
```

Example usage:

```
functions = [type, id, hex]
for result in apply_all(functions, 55):
    print result
```

gives

```
<type 'int'>
20326112
0x37
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot:

```
def lambda_apply(unnamed_funcs, element):
    for unnamed in unnamed_funcs:
        yield unnamed(element)

>>> l = [lambda x: x**2, lambda x: 2*x]
>>> el = 5

>>> for y in lambda_apply(l, el):
...     print y
... 
25
10
```

Note that this works not only for a list of unnamed functions, but any list of functions of [arity 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity). This is because all functions, named or not, are first class objects in python. You can store them in a list, and use them later, as demonstrated above.

Comment: there is a typo in your function: it should read `yield` instead of `yeild`

Comment: Yep, just caught that. Isn't syntax highlighting on SO wonderful? (seriously, it's the best).

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be formulated as

```
import numpy as np

def apply_funcs( funcs, val ):
    for func in funcs:
        yield func(val)

my_funcs = [lambda x: np.cos(x), np.sin, np.tan]
my_val = 0.1

for res in apply_funcs( my_funcs, my_val ):
    print res
```

where the `apply_funcs` function does the trick and the rest is just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you necessarily need a `yield` statement?

Because there is another way to create generator: to use `()`.

```
applied_it = (f(item) for f in functions)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def apply(value, lambda_list):
    for function in lambda_list:
          yield (function(value))
```